# how can I destroy a wvega timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I need to destroy a timepicker but there's no doc on how to call the method:

```
var tp = $('.timefield').timepicker();
```

Comment: What do you mean by `destroy`?

Comment: It is just a set of HTML with some Dom, simply `$(.'timefield').remove()`

Comment: No, I don't want to remove the field, I want to destroy the timepicker instance. Because it seems if you initialize it twice, it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right there's no mention on this in their docs. but I've used it; this is how you destroy [wvega timepicker](https://github.com/wvega/timepicker) so that it behaves like a regular text field

```
$('.timefield').timepicker('destroy');
```

Comment: This is the correct syntax. I think I tried it but it doesn't work the way it should.  init-destroy-init throws errors. I've moved on to a different plugin.